# Пустой аргумент в функции python

Tags: python

хочу чтобы он выводил мне "Как хорошо что ты молчишь", если я введу пустое значение при вызове функции

```
def chat_bot(phrase):
if phrase[-1] == "?":
    return "Конечно"
elif phrase == phrase.upper():
    return "Успокойся"
elif phrase == # если аргумент будет пустым
    return "Как хорошо что ты молчишь"
else:
    return "ну и что?"
```

print(chat_bot())

Comment: `elif not phrase:`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/achi/PycharmProjects/homeworks/october/homework_29_10_18/task10.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(chat_bot())
TypeError: chat_bot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'phrase'

Comment: @floydya, в вышеприведенном контексте `elif not phrase:`  не вариант, поскольку первое условие `if phrase[-1] == "?":` при пустой строке вызовет исключение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def chat_bot(phrase=''): # задаем значение по умолчанию - пустая строка
    if not phrase: # если аргумент будет пустым (Пустая строка == False)
                   # строка содержашая что либо == True
                   # ставим это условие в самое начало потому,
                   # что следующее условие обращается к элементам строки
                   # по индексу, а в пустой строке нет элементов
                   # соответственно нет индексов. Поэтому будет исключение
        return "Как хорошо что ты молчишь"
    if phrase[-1] == "?":
        return "Конечно"
    if phrase == phrase.upper():
        return "Успокойся"
    return "ну и что?"
```

### Немного доосмыслил :-)))

```
def chat_bot(phrase=''):
    from random import choice
    q_reply = ['Конечно.', 'Естественно.', 'Ну конечно-же.', 'Именно так.', 'Надо подумать']
    w_reply = ['Успокойся.', 'Тише, тише, не ори.', 'Ну зачем так громко?', 'Не нервничай.']
    o_reply = ['Ну и что?', 'Как скажешь.', 'Ну а как же...', 'Ну а я о чем?']
    s_reply = ['Как хорошо, что ты молчишь.', 'Погромче, я не слышу.', 'Тишина - это здорово.']
    if not phrase:  # если аргумент будет пустым
        return choice(s_reply)
    if phrase[-1] == "?":
        return choice(q_reply)
    if phrase == phrase.upper():
        return choice(w_reply)
    return choice(o_reply)


print(chat_bot('Придешь?'))  # Надо подумать
print(chat_bot('Волшебная фигня'))  # Ну и что?
print(chat_bot('РАЗБЕРИСЬ В СЕБЕ'))  # Тише, тише, не ори.
print(chat_bot())  # Как хорошо, что ты молчишь.
print(chat_bot('Придешь?'))  # Ну конечно-же.
```

Comment: шик. Работает) Спасибо)

Comment: @ChyngyzAkmatov, лучшее спасибо - зеленая галочка на ответе ))) На здоровье )

Comment: @ChyngyzAkmatov, немного развил тему. Глянте.

Answer (score -2):

?

```
def chat_bot(phrase):
    if phrase[-1] == "?":
        return "Конечно"
    elif phrase == phrase.upper():
        return "Успокойся"
    elif not phrase:
        return "Как хорошо что ты молчишь"
    else:
        return "ну и что?"
```

Comment: Если фраза будет пустой то `if phrase[-1] == "?":` бросит исключение